# What's that long garbled string of character and the end of Ocra or Ruby2Exe?

Tags: ruby, windows, lzma

Here's a part of it...

```
__END__
24295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```

Is this something to do with LZMA compression? Like a seed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to be a base64-encoded DOS/Windows executable.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it could just be ruby data.  Anything after `__END__` in a ruby program can be treated as a data file, and accessed using the special constant DATA.

```
$ cat test.rb
DATA.each_line{|l| puts l}
__END__
one
two
three
four
$ ruby test.rb
one
two
three
four
$
```